# Convert type of a columns in datatable

Tags: string, types, datatable, format, clone

I import a csv file into a datatable which, unfortunately, put my datas into string columns even those with figures.

So I have to convert the format of some columns (unless there is an other way) into datetime, integer or double why I wrote the following code :

```
Public Sub ChangeFieldType(ByRef dataTable As DataTable, ByVal fieldIndex As Integer, ByVal newType As Type)
    Dim newDataTable As DataTable = dataTable.Clone

    newDataTable.Columns(fieldIndex).DataType = newType
    For Each row As DataRow In dataTable.Rows
        newDataTable.ImportRow(row)
    Next
    dataTable = newDataTable
End Sub
```

But there are some empty cells which in string format is vbnullstring. My question is is there an easier way then my code and if not is there an faster way than converting the empty cells then that way :

```
Public Sub ChangeFieldType(ByRef dataTable As DataTable, ByVal fieldIndex As Integer, ByVal newType As Type)
    Dim newDataTable As DataTable = dataTable.Clone

    newDataTable.Columns(fieldIndex).DataType = newType
    For Each row As DataRow In dataTable.Rows
        If row(fieldIndex) = vbNullString Then
            row(fieldIndex) = Nothing
        End If
        newDataTable.ImportRow(row)
    Next
    dataTable = newDataTable
End Sub
```

Because this is very very slow.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When importing the csv file if you already know the column types beforehand then you should make a table with those columns and then fill the data. Cloning a table and then filling the data again is very slow process especially if data is large

You can refer to the following
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/34b6a1e8-5103-42a3-aa45-cdc0cea461f2/importing-csv-file-to-datatable-problem-with-converting-data-type

Comment: I tried your solution but i'm getting then a cast exception during the import of the csvfile into the datatable.  The exception says that the expected type is Double instead of String. My code for importing is the following:
`While csvCopy.ReadNextRecord()
                    Dim csvRow As DataRow = datatable.NewRow
                    For i = 0 To csvCopy.FieldCount - 1
                        csvRow(i) = csvCopy(i)
                    Next
                    datatable.Rows.Add(csvRow)
                End While`

And it freezes on `csvRow(i) = csvCopy(i)`

Comment: You are doing it exactly wrong as the op in the link. Please use the method shown in answer in that page

Answer (score 0):

**Use the below Code To Convert The Data type of a Column in DataTable**

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table = GetTable();

        DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("MyDate", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        table.Columns.Add(dc);

        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            row["MyDate"] =Convert.ToDateTime(row["Date"].ToString()).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = table;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }



    static DataTable GetTable()
    {
        // Here we create a DataTable with four columns.
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("SortName", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("FullName", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

        // Here we add five DataRows.
        table.Rows.Add(25, "Geli", "Smruti", DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        table.Rows.Add(50, "Gelu", "Ramesh", DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        table.Rows.Add(10, "Nitu", "Mama", DateTime.Now.AddDays(3).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        table.Rows.Add(21, "Babu", "Gelu", DateTime.Now.AddDays(4).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));        
        return table;
    }
}
```

Add a Column To Existing DataTable & Update the Data to The new Column Which you Want to Change the DataType.